# How to resume package building in debian?

Tags: debian, package-management, dpkg, packaging, pkgbuild

I am running  debian stretch and following [this guide](https://coderwall.com/p/urkybq/how-to-create-debian-package-from-source) for building package from source for debian.

Sometimes building process takes hours , when I run  `dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot` again , it starts building from scratch.

`dpkg-buildpackage --help`  does not show any option to resume.

How can I resume package building  ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To continue a build that was interrupted for some reason, you can call the appropriate targets of `debian/rules` directly:

```
debian/rules build
```

will compile the sources, then

```
fakeroot debian/rules binary
```

will run the installation and prepare the packages.

Answer (score 5):

I have been using the `-nc` switch for this. According to the [man](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/dpkg-dev/dpkg-buildpackage.1.en.html) page:

```
-nc, --no-pre-clean
    Do not clean the source tree before building (long option since
    dpkg 1.18.8). Implies -b if nothing else has been selected among
    -F, -g, -G, -B, -A or -S. Implies -d with -S (since dpkg 1.18.0).
```